# Finding date by subtracting X number of days from a particular date in Javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I want to find date by subtracting  X number of days from a particular date in JavaScript. My JavaScript function accepts 2 parameters. One is the date value and the other is the number of days that needs to be subtracted.

For example,  I pass my argument date as 27 July 2009   and i pass my other argument as 3. So i want to calculate the date 3 days before 27 July 2009. So the resultant date that we should get is 24 July 2009. How is this possible in JavaScript. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Simply:

```
yourDate.setDate(yourDate.getDate() - daysToSubtract);
```

Comment: I don't think this will work unless the current day of the month is more than the days you are subtracting.

Comment: ... for example it works today with -3 because today is the 27 (in the US, but if today was the 2nd, you'd end up with the new date being -1 and setDate will die if you try to set the day of the month to a negative number.

Comment: @tvanfosson- thanks for noting this point.Bad me....I will try all the methods and get back...

Comment: @all: This will work for all cases.  If setDate gets a negative value then it sets the date back into the previous month as you would hope.  This is much easier than subtracting days in milliseconds.

Comment: This will not work in all cases. See the Ash Wednesday example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9036838/javascript-subtracting-days-from-date

Comment: Hi Ron...the Ash Wednesday example's code contains a logic error that explains the bad results.  It subtracts 1 month from the Easter date, then subtracts 46 days, when the author intended only to subtract 46 days.  Thus, he gets Ash Wednesdays in December, &c.

Comment: Don't get confused by the actual `Date()` object, which you subtract milliseconds from, not days.

Comment: We had a situation when this failed for us on OSX Safari (maybe something to do with daylight savings?). We changed to something like `new Date (d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), -1)` which fixed the problem (See ron-tornambe's comment and link above).

Comment: This does not work if the range falls over daylight saving

Answer (score 23):

```
function date_by_subtracting_days(date, days) {
    return new Date(
        date.getFullYear(), 
        date.getMonth(), 
        date.getDate() - days,
        date.getHours(),
        date.getMinutes(),
        date.getSeconds(),
        date.getMilliseconds()
    );
}
```

Comment: This worked and IMHO is the best answer.  Each of the others would return 38 say if I added 7 days to the 31st of a month.  Thank you!

Comment: This approach has proven more reliable for me - it returns a `Date` object, where the accepted answer gives me an `Int`

Comment: And what happens if you are on Day 1 of a month, and you subtract days and it goes negative? Does `Date` handle that?

Comment: This also worked for me while the accepted answer failed

Comment: I would upvote this answer, but I have a rigid personal policy of never upvoting code-only answers -- they role model bad answer posting practices.  When new users see that code-only answers from high-rep users can earn unicorn points, they think it is okay to do.  If this answer is ever improved, please ping me so that I can upvote.

Answer (score 9):

Never go for this solution 
yourDate.setDate(yourDate.getDate() - daysToSubtract);

it wont work in case your date is 1st of any month and you want to delete some days say 1.

Instead go for below solution which will work always

var newDate = new Date( yourDate.getTime() - (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) );

Comment: This was the best and simplest solution I've found so far that handles all boundary cases which everyone else seems to be ignoring. Thanks!

Comment: Most dates have a timezone, and this solution can fail for some values that cross daylight savings. This is a common mistake because simple testing doesn't show up the problem e.g. reading a input type=date may cause problems because it unexpectedly has a timezone and a time. It is really difficult to manipulate the time value in milliseconds without ending up with wierd bugs.

Answer (score 2):

Here i am posting one more answer and that will return date in specific format.

First you can get current date **10/08/2013** as below

```
function Cureent_Date() {
    var today_GMT = new Date();
    var dd = today_GMT.getDate();
    var mm = today_GMT.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!
    var yyyy = today_GMT.getFullYear();
    if (dd < 10) {
        dd = '0' + dd
    }
    if (mm < 10) {
        mm = '0' + mm
    }
    current_date = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;
    alert("current_date"+current_date);

    Back_date();
}
```

Now Get back date base on **X** days

```
function Back_date()
{    
    var back_GTM = new Date(); back_GTM.setDate(back_GTM.getDate() - 2); // 2 is your X
    var b_dd = back_GTM.getDate();
    var b_mm = back_GTM.getMonth()+1;
    var b_yyyy = back_GTM.getFullYear();
    if (b_dd < 10) {
        b_dd = '0' + b_dd
    }
    if (b_mm < 10) {
        b_mm = '0' +b_mm
    }

    var back_date=  b_mm + '/' + b_dd + '/' + b_yyyy;
    alert("back_date"+back_date);
}
```

So, Today is `10/08/2013` so it will return `10/06/2013`.

[Check Live Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/fnmTt/26/)
Hope this answer will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example, however this does no kind of checking (for example if you use it on 2009/7/1 it'll use a negative day or throw an error.

```
function subDate(o, days) {
// keep in mind, months in javascript are 0-11
return new Date(o.getFullYear(), o.getMonth(), o.getDate() - days);;
}
```

Comment: That seems to work too (in Safari at least). I was surprised the accepted answer works. Apparently, it will adjust the month / year to return a valid date: e.g., Date(2009, 6, 0) becomes Date(2009, 5, 30).

Comment: Work in both Firefox and Safari for me, including with negative numbers.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do.  Note you can simplify the expression, I've just written it out to make it clear you are multiplying the number of days by the number of milliseconds in a day.

```
 var newDate = new Date( yourDate.getTime() - (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) );
```

Comment: Don't do this; use days instead. This could cause errors in places that observe Daylight Saving Time. For example, `Mar 14 2011` minus 1*24*60*60*1000 is `Mar 12 2011` for me.

Comment: Confirmed. This approach (erroneously or at least unexpectedly) subtracted an extra hour when DST started.

Answer (score 0):

Just another option, which I wrote:

[DP_DateExtensions Library](http://depressedpress.com/javascript-extensions/dp_dateextensions/)

It's probably overkill if ALL you want to do is one calculation, but if you're going to do more date manipulation you might find it useful.

Supports date/time formatting, date math (add/subtract date parts), date compare, date parsing, etc.

Comment: Seems to be working for me... nothing that I can see in the logs - are you still getting it?  What is the error?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> this is in reference to above answer
>   check this fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/uniyalguru/azh65aa0/

```
function Cureent_Date() {
var today_GMT = new Date();
var dd = today_GMT.getDate();
var mm = today_GMT.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!
var yyyy = today_GMT.getFullYear();
if (dd < 10) {
    dd = '0' + dd
}
if (mm < 10) {
    mm = '0' + mm
}
current_date = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a function for date manipulation. you can add or subtract any number of days, hours, minutes.

```
function dateManipulation(date, days, hrs, mins, operator) {
    date = new Date(date);
    if (operator == "-") {
       var durationInMs = (((24 * days) * 60) + (hrs * 60) + mins) * 60000;
       var newDate = new Date(date.getTime() - durationInMs);
    } else {
       var durationInMs = (((24 * days) * 60) + (hrs * 60) + mins) * 60000;
       var newDate = new Date(date.getTime() + durationInMs);
    }
   return newDate;
}
```

Now, call this function by passing parameters. For example, here is a function call for getting date before 3 days from today.

```
var today = new Date();
var newDate = dateManipulation(today, 3, 0, 0, "-");
```