# how to multiplication remaining amount with staying days? how to do that in java script?

Tags: php, javascript

how to multiplication remaining amount with staying days? how to do that in java script?

for example

```
function getObj(objID){

var val=document.getElementById(objID);

if (val=="") { return 0;} else { return val; }

function D(){

    var cash =document.getElementById('cash').value;    

var total =document.getElementById('total').value;

var prepaid = document.getElementById('prepaid').value;

var remain = document.getElementById('remain').value;


document.getElementById('prepaid').value= parseFloat(getObj('cash').value);

document.getElementById('remain').value = (parseFloat(getObj('prepaid').value))-(parseFloat(getObj('total').value));


    }
  `
```

Comment: Your question is very confusing can you elaborate a bit about which part isn't working?

Comment: all are working part but i want idea how to do that in javascript

Comment: in getObj function val will be either null or HTMLElement. You should test for null even though your code work because all elements are present.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look like you did a search before you asked this question, but it's pretty well covered here and in other questions: [Javascript subtracting days from date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9036838/javascript-subtracting-days-from-date)

Disclaimer: You will need to scroll down once arriving at this page.

Comment: i can't understood can you give me proper example please thanks

Comment: this code is for This code where I subtract days from a date does not get the right results.

Comment: It's not clear then, what you're looking to do other than a subtraction problem. What do you expect to be returned, a number? A day of the week? Please be specific. Thank you.

Comment: for example remaining amount 100 and today date is 10/9/2012 and staying days is 10 days and staying till date 10/19/2012.. remaining amount 100 + per day charge * 10 = ???