# Given a ISO 8601 weeknumber, how would you get the dates within that week

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got a weeknumber from a jquery datepicker, when a user selects a date. But now I want to get all the days within that week.

I could add a click event that loops through all the td's of the tr the selected date is in and graps it's value but I'm looking for a more reliable way.

So my question is, given a certain date and a weeknumber (iso 8601 formatted), how can you derive the other dates within that week with javascript?

Comment: How does an ISO 8601 formatted week look like?

Comment: sorry I ment Iso 8601 formatted date not weeknumber. So: year month day

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can solve it by subtracting the selected date day (getDate()), with the day of the week (getDay()). This way you have the first day of the week. Then you can use a for loop till 7, to get all the other days. You don't need the weeknumber.

```
var selected_date = $(this).datepicker('getDate'); //the date the user has clicked
var first_day_of_the_week = new Date(selected_date.getFullYear(),selected_date.getMonth(),selected_date.getDate() - selected_date.getDay() + 1);

var days = [];
for(var i = 0; i < 7; i++){
    var day = new Date(first_day_of_the_week.getFullYear(), 
        first_day_of_the_week.getMonth(),   
        first_day_of_the_week.getDate() + i);

    days.push(day);
}

console.log(days);
```

Answer (score 0):

There’s a JavaScript implementation of a `getWeek` function here:

- http://www.meanfreepath.com/support/getting_iso_week.html

You could run that on dates seven days either side of your date, and keep the dates for which the week number is the same.

Comment: This still would require for me to loop all the DOM elements to subtract the dates, and then compare if they are within the week.

Comment: Ah, no — I meant you could create new Date objects from your existing date object. `var one_day_earlier = new Date; one_day_earlier.setDate( existing_date.getDate() - 1 );`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187824/finding-date-by-subtracting-x-number-of-days-from-a-particular-date-in-javascrip