# Javascript create image gallery from filenames containing dates

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, html, date

Guys I am going crazy over this and I know there are allot of contraints using javascript, but the site I am building only has html files. I can use php as well, but it needs to be a seperate file that can be referenced, but not included. The final extension needs to be .html

That said I am making a photo of the day script to take a directory of images with image names that contain dates. for example today's image of the day is **20120822.jpg** and there is a huge directory of images going until the end of the year. Tomorrow's image will be **20120823.jpg** and yesterday was **20120821.jpg**

Ok that part was sort of simple.. but now I want to create a gallery made up off all the images previously displayed.. so every image leading up to the current date's filename. So i need to either read the directory or just generate the last 20 images that lead up to the current image's date filename. I would settle for the previous 20 images or something.

Here is the code I am using for the photo of the day.. any idea how I would do that?

```
    <script>


     //returns the current date in YYYYMMDDf_01.jpg format
     function getCurrentDateString(){

       //make a new date object set at the current date
       var currentDate = new Date();

       //get the four position year and
       //make it a string
       var currentYear = currentDate.getFullYear() + "";

       //get the zero-indexed month and add 1
       //for the real month and make it a strintg
       var currentMonth = (currentDate.getMonth() + 1) + "";

       //add a zero at the beginning if only one
       //digit month
       if (currentMonth.length == 1) {
         currentMonth = "0" + currentMonth;
       }

       //get the current day of the month and
       //make it a string
       var currentDayOfMonth = currentDate.getDate() + "";

       //add a zero if necessary
       if (currentDayOfMonth.length == 1) {
         currentDayOfMonth = "0" + currentDayOfMonth;
       }

       return(currentYear + currentMonth + currentDayOfMonth);
     }

     //preload image based upon currentDate
     var currentDateString = getCurrentDateString();

     var dailyImageObject = new Image();

      var dailyImageObjectURL = new Image();

     dailyImageObject.src = "http://perillotours.com/galleries/photo-of-the-day/images/" +         currentDateString + ".jpg";

     dailyImageObjectURL.href = "http://perillotours.com/galleries/photo-of-the-day/images/" + currentDateString + ".jpg";

     //called when the page loads to
     //set the actual HTML IMG element to have the same
     //SRC as our cached Image object
     function showDailyImage(){
       document.getElementById("dailyIMGElement").src = dailyImageObject.src;
     }
      function showDailyImageURL(){
       document.getElementById("dailyIMGElementURL").href = dailyImageObjectURL.href;
     }

     </script>
```

here is the code that I place in the html page to display the photo of the day.

```
    <a rel="prettyphoto" id="dailyIMGElementURL">
    <img width="523" style="background-color: #000000;" id="dailyIMGElement" height="335" border="0" /></a>
```

So basically I want to loop the above code like 20 times with the last 20 images. Anythoughts I really can't think of how to do it..

THanks so much in advance for any help or ideas!

Ian

Comment: You need to generate the `html` part of your code with something like jquery's `html()`...20 times in a loop which calls the `getCurrentDateString()` with varying dayOfMonth numbers. 1,2,3,4... for showing images for tomorrow, day after tomorrow and so on and -1,-2,-3,-4 for showing images for yesterday, day before and so on...Also, the html also needs to be correspondingly revised. You can write a function for html generation which is called from `getCurrentDateString` to generate the prev & next links with suitable calls.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not reference any jQuery, so assuming you wish to use jQuery:

1. Start with a loop - This way you can easily define how many images you want. By using the date object you dont have to worry about subtracting to many days. (Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/qH8xX/2/)

   ```
   var html = "";
   for( i = 0; i < 20; i++ ) {
       html += "<li>" + i + "</li>";
   }

   $("#gallery").html( html );
   ```
2. In the loop, subtract 1 from the date and then save it as the date. (Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/qH8xX/3/)

   ```
   var html = "";
   var date = new Date(); // store the current date

   for( i = 0; i < 20; i++ ) {
       // subtract 1 from date
       // more here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187824/finding-date-by-subtracting-x-number-of-days-from-a-particular-date-in-javascrip
       date = new Date( date.setDate( date.getDate() - 1 ) );
       html += "<li>" + i + " = " + date.toDateString() + "</li>";
   }

   $("#gallery").html( html );
   ```

​3. Your turn: Now use the date object to create an image tag with the correct filename. Using this will help: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp