# Javascript Date manipulation

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Finding date by subtracting X number of days from a particular date in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187824/finding-date-by-subtracting-x-number-of-days-from-a-particular-date-in-javascrip)

I have a [jQuery datepicker](http://stefangabos.ro/jquery/zebra-datepicker/) which allows users to pick a Friday from any given week. I want to populate fields based off that Friday and input the dates from Mon-Thurs as well.

I.e. the user picks this coming Friday (10-26-2012), I want to subtract from the day by 1 to get Thursday date, and then Wed, etc etc.

How would I approach this?

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#friDate").Zebra_DatePicker({
            format: 'm-d-Y',
            disabled_dates: ['* * * 0-4,6'],
            first_day_of_week: 0,
            onSelect: function(){
                var date = $("#friDate").val();
                $("#mon").val('INSERT MON DATE');
                $("#tue").val('INSERT TUE DATE');
                $("#wed").val('INSERT WED DATE');
                $("#thu").val('INSERT THU DATE');
                $("#fri").val(date);                    
            }
        });
    });
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks :).

Comment: Using a date manipulation library is probably your easiest bet. Search 'date.js'.

Comment: Have you looked at the docs for [Date()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)?

Comment: @ahren Suggesting a library for something so simple is overkill

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To subtract a day from an existing date, just subtract the number of milliseconds in a day.

```
var today = new Date();
var yesterday = new Date(today.getTime() - 1000*60*60*24);

// As pointed out by Waxen, we need to account for daylight savings changes
function addDays(date, days) {
    var newDate = new Date(date.getTime() + (1000*60*60*24*days) );
    // To account for daylight savings differences
    // The hours won't be the same when crossing the daylight savings changes
    var hourDifference =  newDate.getHours() - date.getHours();
    var msInHour = 60*60*1000;
    if (hourDifference > 0) {
        newDate = new Date(newDate.getTime() + msInHour) ;
    } else if (hourDifference < 0){
        newDate = new Date(newDate.getTime() - msInHour) ;    
    }    
    return newDate;    
}
```

So for your code, you could do the following

```
$("#mon").val(addDays(date, -4));
$("#tue").val(addDays(date, -3));
$("#wed").val(addDays(date, -2);
$("#thu").val(addDays(date, -1));
$("#fri").val(date);
```

**UPDATE** Though my code works, Waxen's solution is simpler and I would use that. I'll leave this answer here for reference

Comment: Ahahah I feel like a fool. Thank you so much, that is perfect!

Comment: @FunkyMonk91 Thanks to Waxen, I've improved the function so it also works across daylight savings changes

Answer (score 2):

Juan's soulution will work most of the time, but when making assumptions about the number of seconds in a day, you can run into some issues with DST.  I would recommend using the following alternative implementation of his addDays function:

```
function addDays(date, days) {
    var new_date = new Date( date.getTime() );
    new_date.setDate( new_date.getDate() + days );
    return new_date;
}
```

Comment: How would I get the date returned to me in m-d-y format?

Comment: @FunkyMonk91 That is a new question, you should search for it on SO, if you don't find an answer that suits you, you should post a new question. One question per post makes the site more useful

Comment: @Waxen Here's a case where my example would break http://jsfiddle.net/JbxRq/1 when falling back an hour

Comment: Edited my code so that it works across daylight savings changes http://jsfiddle.net/JbxRq/2/

Comment: Here's a case where your code breaks http://jsfiddle.net/JbxRq `addDays(Jan1, -1)` It seems that `setDate` doesn't handle negative values well, sometimes, when crossing month/year

Comment: @JuanMendes, The fiddle you give there actually behaves as expected. `jan1.setDate(jan1.getDate()-1) === jan1.setDate(0)` not `jan1.setDate(-1)`

See this update: http://jsfiddle.net/Waxen/JbxRq/3/

Comment: That's correct, my bad, off by just one :)

Comment: :-)  Took me a minute to figure out what was going on; I use that method in production code where DST is a factor, and I knew it worked there.