# javascript date - 1 day

Tags: javascript, date

I have array with some dates:

```
periods[i].start
periods[i].ende
```

Initially I populate start date. Then I want to calculate end date, like this:

```
periods[i].ende = periods[i+1].start - 1 day
```

This works:

```
periods[i].ende = periods[i+1].start;
```

But how to do: `-1` day?

Thanks!

EDIT: It's not duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187824/finding-date-by-subtracting-x-number-of-days-from-a-particular-date-in-javascrip). Method setDate works for a single variable like YOURDATE, but not for something like PERIODS[i].ENDE. Difference - maybe one is reference, other is value.
I used this code:

```
function finalizePeriods() {
  var tempDay;
  for(var i=0; i<periods.length - 1; i++) {
    tempDay = new Date(periods[i+1].start);
    tempDay.setDate(tempDay.getDate() - 1);
    periods[i].ende = tempDay;
  }
}
```

MBottens, thanks again!

Comment: Read about the javascript date object.

Comment: This doesn't work:   

periods[i].ende.setDate(periods[i].ende.getDate()-1);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heres one way of doing it. This will set each end date except for the last one. Since there is not a date to calculate it from.

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/FGt4B/1/

```
var periods = [{start: "5/1/2014"}, {start: "5/8/2014"}, {start: "5/15/2014"}],
    period, nextPeriod, tempDay

for ( var i = 0, _len = periods.length; i < _len; i++ ) {
    period = periods[i]
    nextPeriod = periods[i+1]

    if ( nextPeriod ) {
        tempDay = new Date(nextPeriod.start)
        tempDay.setDate(tempDay.getDate() -1)
        period.end = tempDay.toLocaleDateString()
    }
}

console.log(periods)
```

Comment: That didn't answer the question. It works, but I don't have simple variable like 'day'

Comment: 'tempDay' worked! Thanks, MBottens!

Answer (score 0):

A suggestion may be to use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) library. Then just

```
moment.subtract('days', 1);
```