# dc.js - add drop down to select date range

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

I'm using dc.js to display some info, I would like to add a drop down to select the date range as - All, last 7 days, last 30 days, last 90 days.

How would I add that to the following?

```
var dataTable = dc.dataTable("#dc-table-graph");

var data = [
 {date: "2014-08-15T06:30:43Z", amount: 10},
 {date: "2014-08-12T10:30:43Z", amount: 10 },
 {date: "2014-08-1T16:28:54Z", amount: 100 },
 {date: "2014-07-28T18:48:46Z", amount: 100 },
 {date: "2014-07-26T20:53:41Z", amount: 11 },
 {date: "2014-07-16T10:53:41Z", amount: 5 },
 {date: "2014-05-1T22:54:06Z", amount: 10 },
 {date: "2013-11-1T10:30:43Z", amount: 2 },
 ];

var dtgFormat = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ");

data.forEach(function (d) {
  d.date   = dtgFormat.parse(d.date.substr(0,20));
  d.amount  = +d.amount;
  d.type = d.type;
});


var ndx = crossfilter(data);
var timeDimension = ndx.dimension(
  function (d) {return d.date;});

dataTable.width(960).height(800)
  .dimension(timeDimension)
  .group(function(d) { return "" })
  .size(20)
  .columns([
    function(d) { return d.date; },
    function(d) { return d.amount; },
  ])
  .sortBy(function(d){ return d.date; })
  .order(d3.ascending);

dc.renderAll();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/northside45/uvxzo785/

Comment: For anyone reading this question, here is a new question with a fixed fiddle for the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33689331/how-to-filter-precisely-on-date/33694581#33694581

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add another dimension on time so that it affects the dimension for your data table. (In crossfilter, filtering a dimension will only affect other dimensions, not itself.)

Then use `filterRange` on that other dimension in response to your dropdown.

https://github.com/square/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#wiki-dimension_filterRange

Comment: I'm managing to filter my results with the drop down to a new variable but having trouble understanding how to now update the dataTable, which I'm sure is simple but I can't get it working! Please look here - http://jsfiddle.net/northside45/uvxzo785/

Comment: You should call `filterRange` on the dimension object with two dates (presumably now minus N days and now) in order to set the dimension filter. Calling `.top` just returns an array without modifying the filter.

Comment: OK, I see what you mean. I'm currently having difficulty on setting those 2 dates to do the filterRange on. I've set them manually to match dates but that doesn't work. Do these need to be set as decimals?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187824/finding-date-by-subtracting-x-number-of-days-from-a-particular-date-in-javascrip

Comment: Thanks @Gordon that's got me going down the right track now!

Comment: I have the filterRange working great if I manually set the range, or if I manually set the first value and use `now = new Date();`. However I do not understand why this doesn't work, I'm sure I'm missing something obvious.
`now = new Date();`
`newdate = new Date(now);
newdate.setDate(newdate.getDate() - 30);
nd = new Date(new date);`
`timeDimension.filterRange([nd, now]);`

Comment: Is that your actual code? The next to last statement looks fishy - I'm not sure what result you would get for `new date` given that `date` (lower case d) probably doesn't exist. That statement shouldn't be needed anyhow, you can just use `newdate` directly in your last statement. Using a debugger, setting a breakpoint on the last line, and examining variables helps a LOT for troubleshooting such things.