# How to filter precisely on date?

Tags: dc.js

I'm using a lineChart to show created date (one field in my data), it works fine and I can select, but I need a more precise filter: only for items created today, this week, last week, this month, last month

Is there already an example of how it's done? I'm struggling on how to apply a daterange filter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this question comes up now and then and it would be nice to have a decent example, I went back to NorthSide's question from a while back and fixed up the fiddle.

[dc.js - add drop down to select date range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25246070/dc-js-add-drop-down-to-select-date-range)

We'll define a second time dimension so that the charts are affected by it.

In this example we set the number of days as the option value, and then use that to calculate the date:

```
<select id="myDropDown">
  <option value="Infinity">All</option>
  <option value='30'>30 days</option>
  <option value='7'>7 days</option>
  <option value="2">Top 2 day</option>
  <option value="5">Top 5 day</option>
</select>

d3.select('#myDropDown').on('change', function(){ 
    var nd = new Date(now);
    nd.setDate(nd.getDate() - +this.value);
    filterDimension.filterRange([nd, now]);
    dc.redrawAll();    
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/400wd2nd/16/

There are more intelligent ways to calculate a month back and so on, but hopefully this is enough to get you started.

Comment: awesome, I'll fiddle around a bit on my context and come back here.

Comment: Updated fiddle of Gordon:http://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/400wd2nd/16/

Answer (score 1):

I added a feature to be able to select the current day, current week or 
current month:

```
  d3.select('#date_select').on('change', function(){ 
    var nd = new Date(), now = new Date();
    switch (this.value) {
      case "today":
        nd = d3.time.day(now);
        break;
      case "week":
        nd = d3.time.monday(now);
        break;
      case "month":
        nd = d3.time.month(now);
        break;
      default:
        nd.setDate(nd.getDate() - +this.value);
    }
    dim.filterAll();
    dim.filterRange([nd, now]);
    //did not work graph.replaceFilter(dc.RangedFilter(nd, now));
    graph.redrawGroup();
  });
```

and the html being:

```
<select id="date_select">
  <option value="Infinity">All</option>
  <option value="today">Today</option>
  <option value='1'>last 24 hours</option>
  <option value="week">This week</option>
  <option value="month">This month</option>
  <option value='30'>last 30 days</option>
  <option value='90'>last 90 days</option>
</select>
```