# substracting days to date loop

Tags: javascript, date

Here's the code :

```
    var date = new Date(annee, mois, jour);
    var i = 0;
    while (i < 365) {
        date.setTime(date.getTime()-(1000*60*60*24*i));
        console.log(date.getFullYear()+'/'+parseInt(date.getMonth()+1)+'/'+date.getDate());
        i++;
    }
```

I'm trying to substract 1 day per loop, but i get this :

```
2016/1/13
2016/1/11
2016/1/8
2016/1/4
2015/12/30
2015/12/24
2015/12/17
2015/12/9
2015/11/30
2015/11/20
[...]
1834/2/27
```

after a quick look on stack's solution, I found this : [Finding date by subtracting X number of days from a particular date in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187824/finding-date-by-subtracting-x-number-of-days-from-a-particular-date-in-javascrip?newreg=6c8f8cc9e7084c8bad830349eb7df692) But the result is always a bunch of false days ... 
I tried by `getDate()-days`, `setTime(getTime()-(different ms calculs))` - **as in code** -, trying with utc gmt and iso ...

well ... hope someone can help me :/ thanks !

Comment: date.setDate(date.getDate() - 1) should do the trick

Comment: Note that removing 8.64e7 milliseconds from a date may not remove exactly one day over daylight saving boundaries, BeNdErR's suggestion is a good one. Oh, and there is no need for *parseInt* in `parseInt(date.getMonth()+1)`, though the expression needs to be in brackets to separate it from the concatenation: `... + (date.getMonth()+1) + ...`. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove multiplication by i. It subtracts i days.

```
var date = new Date(annee, mois, jour);
    var i = 0;
    while (i < 365) {
        date.setTime(date.getTime()-(1000*60*60*24)); //removed *i
        console.log(date.getFullYear()+'/'+parseInt(date.getMonth()+1)+'/'+date.getDate());
        i++;
    }
```

Comment: Awwwww, i'm feeling so dumb right now. Big thanks :/

Answer (score 0):

Dates are really hard. Even though it seems like an easy calculation, what happens if the date is the first of the month - would you expect the date to rollback to the last month? What if it is the first day of the year? Or the 1st March and it is a leap year?

I'd recommend deferring tasks like this to a library such as http://momentjs.com/ or http://sugarjs.com/dates.

Comment: Dates aren't that hard. Subtracting a day from say 1 Jan will get 31 December. They are just a time value with some handy methods, that's it.